# extend camel http to add common header for all http request

Tags: apache-camel

currently, for a server to server communication, we have our own authentication method which will expect a random key in the HTTP request header.is there a way I can extend the camle HTTP to add the header for all the HTTP request call. Note we have 4 camel context XML and each camel context have 10 routes which make the HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Camel interceptors in order to add your custom header to (all or some) "http:*"-like endpoints.
Have a look at:
http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html